# Why is visual studio blurring the fonts

Tags: windows-10, intel, nvidia, visual-studio-2017

I recently updated my notebook and did a clean install of windows 10. I have a dual graphic cards (nvidia 850m & intel 4600hd). it took a while to set up everything correctly and I have the machine working like it should. The only thing that bothers me is that VS is blurring the fonts like the picture, like I have a bad refresh rate or something and I can't figure out what. Do I need to install the original drivers (from 3 years ago) for windows to detect correctly the graphic cards it is something else causing the issue?

The funny thing is if I resize the font (using the mouse wheel) it gets fixed for a few seconds and the blurry again. I didn't see any other issues outside visual studio

Help me stackoverflow, you are my only hope!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with blurred fonts but after installing `Windows Creators Update` it went away.